# How to blacklist Terminal Services startup environment setting?

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, rdp

I have a user in Active Directory who uses this setting in the Environment tab:

> Start the following program at logon:
>   "C:\Program Files\PName\Folder\gui.exe"

This runs okay on various computers (that are on the domain) including his own. But the user needs to RDP into a Windows Server which does not have this program (which is normal).

When the user RDPs into the server and logs in with the AD account, an error occurs about C:\Program Files\PName\Folder\gui.exe missing and the user then gets stuck at a grey screen.

The user needs to RDP into this server; how can one blacklist that Environment setting from activation on a specific machine on the domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new GPO that disallow login scripts from running and apply it to your AD Server objects.

http://sourcedaddy.com/windows-7/how-to-disable-startup-applications-configured-using-group-policy-or-logon-scripts.html

Comment: I only need to disallow this login script on this specific user and no one else. Will this do that?

Comment: You could create a User GPO, then create an AD OU for the user and RDP servers and apply the GPO on that OU.